# Postgresql - Find first gap in INET range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got the following table structure for storing IPs (`PostgreSQL`):

```
CREATE TABLE ips (
  ip INET NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ips VALUES ('127.0.0.1');
INSERT INTO ips VALUES ('127.0.0.5');
INSERT INTO ips VALUES ('127.0.0.6');
```

How can I find `127.0.0.2` as it is the next free lowest IP?

I'm kinda stuck on how to approach this in an optimized way.

This seems to do it, but a way to slow with subnet size /10 (4M+ records):

```
SELECT sub.ip FROM
(SELECT set_masklen(((generate_series(1, (2 ^ (32 - masklen('127.0.0.0/10'::cidr)))::integer - 2) + '127.0.0.0/10'::cidr)::inet), 32) as ip) AS sub
WHERE sub.ip NOT IN
(SELECT ip from ips)
AND sub.ip > set_masklen('127.0.0.0/10', 32)
AND sub.ip < set_masklen(broadcast('127.0.0.0/10')::inet, 32)
ORDER BY ip ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`inet`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html) functions:

```
select ips.ip + 1
from ips
where not exists (select 1 from ips ips2 where ips2.ip = ips.ip + 1)
order by ips.ip
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use version 9.3 or newer, you can take advantage of lateral joins.

```
SELECT (a.ip+1) as low, q.ip as high FROM ips a LEFT JOIN LATERAL
 (SELECT * FROM ips b WHERE a.ip < b.ip ORDER BY b.ip ASC limit 1) AS q ON true
 WHERE q.ip <> (a.ip + 1) LIMIT 1;
```

Join on the same table with the right filters and ordering, then use the `ip + 1`  to generate the next number for each row and check if it matches. Limit results to the first one.

Comment: Why return `q.ip as high`?

Comment: As a reference, so you'd see what's going on.

Comment: Think the last `WHERE q.ip <> (a.ip + 1) ` should be `WHERE q.ip <> (a.ip + 1) order by low asc`.

Answer (score 0):

This function uses a binary search algorithm to efficiently search large address spaces.  It loops, splitting the CIDR block in 2 each iteration and checking for availability in the low and high blocks.  It works with IPv4 and IPv6.

```sql
create or replace function available_ip(inet_cidr cidr)
    returns inet
    language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
    inet_addr_first      inet;
    inet_addr_last       inet;
    inet_cidr_count      numeric;
    inet_cidr_count_low  numeric;
    inet_cidr_count_high numeric;
    inet_cidr_loop       cidr;
    inet_cidr_low        cidr;
    inet_cidr_high       cidr;
    inet_family          int;
    inet_masklen         int;
    inet_masklen_loop    int;
    inet_masklen_max     int;
begin
    -- initialize variables
    -- address family
    inet_family := family(inet_cidr);
    -- CIDR mask length
    inet_masklen := masklen(inet_cidr);
    -- max address max length depends on address family
    case when inet_family = 4 then inet_masklen_max := 32; else inet_masklen_max := 128; end case;
    -- first address in range is the network ID range
    inet_addr_first := set_masklen(inet_cidr :: inet, inet_masklen_max);
    -- last address in range is the broadcast ID
    inet_addr_last := set_masklen(broadcast(inet_cidr :: inet), inet_masklen_max);

    -- ensure there are at least 4 addresses in the CIDR block
    if inet_masklen > inet_masklen_max - 2 then
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'IPv% CIDR mask length should be /% or lower, got /%', inet_family, inet_masklen_max - 2, inet_masklen;
    end if;

    -- loop variables
    inet_cidr_loop := inet_cidr;
    inet_masklen_loop := inet_masklen;

    -- loop
    while inet_masklen_loop < inet_masklen_max
        loop
            -- split the CIDR block in half
            -- increment the mask length
            inet_masklen_loop = inet_masklen_loop + 1;
            -- compute max address count in each half block
            inet_cidr_count = power(2, (inet_masklen_max - inet_masklen_loop));
            -- compute low and high CIDR blocks
            inet_cidr_low := set_masklen(inet_cidr_loop, inet_masklen_loop);
            inet_cidr_high := set_masklen(((inet_cidr_low | ~ netmask(inet_cidr_low)) + 1) :: cidr, inet_masklen_loop);
            -- remove network ID address from low count if it exists in the low CIDR block
            case when inet_cidr_low >>= inet_addr_first then inet_cidr_count_low := inet_cidr_count - 1; else inet_cidr_count_low := inet_cidr_count; end case;
            -- remove broadcast address from high count if it exists in the high CIDR block
            case when inet_cidr_high >>= inet_addr_last then inet_cidr_count_high := inet_cidr_count - 1; else inet_cidr_count_high := inet_cidr_count; end case;

            -- check CIDR blocks for unused addresses
            if (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM ips
                WHERE inet_cidr_low >>= ips.ip) < inet_cidr_count_low then
                -- low CIDR block is not full, loop into it
                inet_cidr_loop := inet_cidr_low;
            elsif (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM ips
                   WHERE inet_cidr_high >>= ips.ip) < inet_cidr_count_high then
                -- high CIDR block is not full, loop into it
                inet_cidr_loop := inet_cidr_high;
            else
                -- both CIDR blocks are full; throw an exception
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'no free IPs in CIDR %', inet_cidr;
            end if;
        end loop;
    return inet_cidr_loop :: inet;
end
$$;
```

To call it:

```sql
SELECT available_ip('127.0.0.0/24');
```